# Adding a white separator between elements in breadcrumbs arrow shaped

Tags: html, css

I have created the following custom breadcrumb (arrow shaped) :

```
    <ol class="breadcrumb-arrow">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1. Foo<span class="arrow"></span></a>                 </li>
        <li ><a href="#">2. Blah<span class="arrow"></span></a></li>
    </ol>
```

CSS:

```
.breadcrumb-arrow {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.breadcrumb-arrow li {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
}
.breadcrumb-arrow li.active {
  background-color: pink;
}
.breadcrumb-arrow li.active a span {
  border-left-color: pink;
  border-top-color: grey;
  border-bottom-color: grey;
}
.breadcrumb-arrow li.active ~ li {
  background-color: grey;
}
.breadcrumb-arrow li.active ~ li a {
  color: black;
}
.breadcrumb-arrow li.active ~ li a span {
  border-left-color: grey;
  border-top-color: grey;
  border-bottom-color: grey;
}
.breadcrumb-arrow li a {
  color: white;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.breadcrumb-arrow li a span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  line-height: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: 15px solid pink;
  border-bottom: 15px solid pink;
}
```

The active element will be in pink, the ones already done will be in black, and the ones to be done will be in grey.
I have used : http://www.lendmeyourear.net/breadcrumb-navigation-with-css-arrows.html as reference.
It works great but I would like to add 2 px of white (arrow shaped) as well between each breadcrumbs element. I guess I have to use :after select.

I haven't been able to do it though, would anyone have an idea ?

Something like this I guess :

```
.breadcrumb-arrow li a span:after { 
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px; 
    left: 100%;
}
```

But I haven't been able to make it work properly.
Here is a plunker : 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Hp9sBSpyiFvTLbw2lCg3?p=preview

Comment: are you having trouble positioning it or making it triangle ? if positioning it's probably cuz it's parent element has 0 height and width so 50% of it's top is still 0.

Comment: Positioning it. Ok, I will try changing the pseudo element, that was only an example though cuz I am not sure about to do the pseudo element at all, so that's obviously not right.

Answer (score 1):

I had a slightly different technique using a z-index hack, increasing left-padding on the "a" tags and and decreasing it on the first-child.

```
.breadcrumb-arrow li a span:after { 
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.breadcrumb-arrow li:first-child a {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

Here's the forked version:
http://plnkr.co/edit/2FvUB6fQ54CLG4Ey0Vu7?p=preview

I hope this helps you, my technique also requires changing the border-color properties of the "li active" span to white as well

Comment: Sounds good, what if I want to reduce or increase the "width" of that white delimiter ? (by instance if I want only 1 px to be visible)

Comment: I'm sure it would be, what sort of control do you have over the underlying html? Wouldn't that be easier to modify or is it coming from a template or theme?